# Eclipse Plugin to receive SVN log in realtime?

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

Is there a Eclipse plugin to get an update notice if there was a comit in the SVN? In realtime? The SVN server I'm using does not provide any RSS log via Track or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a plugin, but rather a standalone application, but maybe it could work for you. The app is called [**CommitMonitor**](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/CommitMonitor). Runs in the system tray and will notify you when there are new commits in the repository

Comment: Thank you, I knew about this tool but still locking for a Eclipse integration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin name as **Team svn** plugin for svn.By using this plugin you can directly commit code from Eclipse itself.And it is having some symbols which shows which files are already committed and which you need to commit.If someone else commit data then it will not allow you to commit first it will force you to take update and then you can commit your code.From last few months I am using this plugin and found very helpful.

Comment: I know about the great integration of using SVN in Eclipse, but I need something like a status update notification...

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the Subversion server does not provide a real time update notice out of the box.

You have to do this work yourself.

First, you have to write a **[hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1)** on the post-commit event.  You could have the Subversion server send a message to a list of URLs or network addresses.

Second, you have to write an Eclipse plug-in to receive the message and update a view status.

Answer (score 0):

With the **Subversive** plugin you can schedule the Synchronize operation.
The operation shows you the differences between your local copy and the svn repository.

To trigger the operation: right click on the project -> Team -> Synchronize with repository

To schedule: on the synchronize view click on the drop down menu (last icon on the top right of the view) -> Schedule

[Source](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/workspace_synch.php)